# Excel: If A does not contain column B then let Column C = A+B

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I'm trying to clean up a sheet of about 4500 entries.
I have some entries where the first and last name are in the same cell and some where they're not. Is there a quick way to say If B is not found in A then add the contents of A and B in C?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean `=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1;"")=A1;A1&" "&B1;A1)`?

Comment: Please check `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A1)),"",A1&" "&B1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use SEARCH to test if there:

```
=A1&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1)),""," "&B1)
```

If it is found the IF returns an empty string to concatenate to A1 if it is not found then it return a space and the value in B.

[image]

---

Or you can just try to remove the value in B and concatenate B:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," "&B1,"")&" "&B1
```

This will remove B from A if found and then just concatenate B onto A.

[image]